# multifunction stopWatch class in Java

Tags: java, timer, stopwatch

I'm writing my first project in java, and I could use some help and experienced view. I'm trying to write stopWatch class, or something more like kitchen timer, which can provide this functionality:

- set hard start and end times,

 - pause and start time from same place 

 - set if the time is decreasing or increasing

 - move in Time up and down

 - addTime (example: watch suppose to start at 00:00 end in 30:00 if we add 35 seconds stopWatch will end at 30:35);

 - display time every second

I didn't find any good thread about this kind of stopWatch/kitchen timer here on stack overflow. My code is working, but I don't really have much of experience with OOD and java generally, so I'm expecting some flaws. It would be reasonable to use some pre-written classes instead? Or Date for time operation?

My code:

```
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.Timer;

// class for handle timer operation
public class stopWatch implements ActionListener {

public Timer timer; // timer object
private int startTime; // start time in seconds
private int endTime; // end time in seconds
private int actualTime; // actual time in seconds
private long memoryUnixTime; // actual time in Unix format 
private boolean decrease; // is Timer decrease or incerease Time? 
private int presize; // how often timer check for change of time

// construct
public stopWatch(int startTime, int endTime, boolean decrease, int presize){
    this.startTime = startTime;
    this.endTime = endTime;
    this.decrease = decrease;
    this.presize = presize;
    this.actualTime = startTime;
}

// moving in Time UP
public void moveTimeUp (int seconds){
    if(inScope("up",seconds))
        actualTime += seconds;
}

// moving in Time DOWN
public void moveTimeDown (int seconds){
    if(inScope("down",seconds))
        actualTime -= seconds;
}


// is added time still inScope
private boolean inScope(String direction,int seconds){
    boolean inScopeP;
    switch(direction){
        case "up":
            inScopeP = ((this.actualTime + seconds) <= this.endTime);
        break;
        case "down":
            inScopeP = ((this.actualTime - seconds) >= this.startTime);
        break;
        default:
            inScopeP = false;
        break;
    }

    return inScopeP;
}

// addTime - this option will be used only if we use increasing timer
public void addTime(int seconds){
    if(this.decrease == false)
        this.endTime += seconds;
}

// run stopwatch
public void run(){
    System.out.println("start");
    this.timer = new Timer(this.presize, this);
    this.timer.setRepeats(true);
    this.timer.start();

}

//stop stopwatch
public void pause(){
    this.timer.stop();
    this.timer = null;

}

// end of counting
public void end(){
    System.out.println("END");
    this.pause();
}

// event listener, handle change time
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    // If the timer caused this event.
    if (e.getSource().equals(timer)) {
        long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

        // If time had change  we decrease or increase time and print it out
        if(changeTimeP(currentTime)){

            // if time`s up we end the counting
            if(this.actualTime == this.endTime){
                this.end();

            // else we do the math increase 
            } else{

                this.memoryUnixTime = currentTime/1000;

                if(decrease == true)
                {
                    this.actualTime--;
                } else {
                    this.actualTime++;
                }

                // println into console for testing purposes
                int min = this.actualTime / 60;
                int sec = this.actualTime % 60;
                System.out.println(min+":"+sec);
            }
        }
    }
}

// did time changed? (in matter of one second)
private boolean changeTimeP(long currentTime){
    if(this.memoryUnixTime != (currentTime/1000L))
        return true;
            else return false;
}

}
```

Peter

Comment: Not an answer, just advice, Learn the difference between `Boolean` and `boolean`. You almost definitely mean to use `boolean`.

Comment: You're right, i wanted use primitive type, thanks for this :-).